# Java servlet how to dump a static html page

Tags: java, servlets

I want to dump a static html page from a servlet.  With php I would do something like

```
$dbdiv = <<<XYZ
<div id="mystaticdiv"></div>
</div>;
```

Then echo the XYZ

Can this be done with Java servletsa?

Comment: Open `FileInputStream` to the page, copy all contents into the servlet outputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) or [`include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), depending on whether it represents full or partial HTML content.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.html").forward(request, response);
```

*(note that the HTML page is hidden away in `/WEB-INF` to prevent direct access without invoking the servlet first)*